# controlling the inner figure margin within grid.layout

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to plot multiple lattice plots in a grid.
To do so I'm using the following code:

```
plot <- xyplot(1:10~1:10)

page.layout <- grid.layout(nrow = 2, ncol = 1,
               widths = unit(c(1), "null"),
               heights = unit(c(1), "null"),
               default.units = "null",
               respect = FALSE,
               just = "centre")

pushViewport(viewport(layout = page.layout))
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row = 1))
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 2))
print(plot, newpage = FALSE)
popViewport()
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row = 2))
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 2))
print(plot, newpage = FALSE)
popViewport()
```

I'd like now to reduce the space between the two figure, I read in the vignette for **gridBase**, that simple graphic controls, such has par`(mar=c())` should be working, but it is not the case here.
Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out, why I can't control the margin parameters.
Any suggestions?

Comment: gridBase is used to mix base and grid graphics, but here you only have grid graphics (lattice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lattice` provides some options to control the plot margins,

```
 p <- xyplot(1:10~1:10,
             par.settings=list(layout.heights=list(top.padding=-3, bottom.padding=-1)))

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p, p, nrow=2)
```

Comment: Thanks baptiste, I’ve been playing with the code you suggested, but even that seems not doing the job. Do you think is possible that on my machine par.setting is not working properly? I’m saying this because I’m also trying to set graphical parameters  (font size, type etc..) globally defining my.theme <- list(par.xlab.text = list(font=3,fontfamily="serif"))  and then calling my theme in xyplot par.setting <- my.theme but even this does not work.

Comment: Let's forget it.. Now it's working fine. Thanks for the suggestion